# How to overcome Waiting for Available Socket (SignalR, C#, ASP.NET WebForms)?

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm currently using SignalR (via hubContex in a WebAPI v2 Controller) to notify users that an email had been sent as our legacy ASP.NET WebForms application has an emailing function that I built from scratch.

However, once a user opens multiple tabs (happens quite so often), Google Chrome starts lagging with an error message that says **waiting for available socket**.

I've tried this link as a workaround:

[Waiting for Available Sockets in ASP.NET using SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668095/waiting-for-available-sockets-in-asp-net-using-signalr)

but I'd like to shed some light on how to actually implement it? I even upvoted the SignalR-IWC library suggestion, hoping that that will solve the issue itself but I really can't make it work. It is imperative to have this notification to let users know wherever tab they are that their email had been sent.

Any ideas on how to implement this? We're using an IIS Server (Windows Server 2016) and Google Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.97).

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The Websocket Protocol of the IIS Server features must be enabled.